# fire event when reCAPTCHA session expires

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I am working on google reCAPTCHA. It's working fine but when reCAPTCHA session expires after certain time and user clicks again on checkbox to fill the reCAPTCHA, google shows alert saying `Error: invalid load parameters.` Nothing works thereafter until user reloads the page.

The `div` block which contains `session expired` message has class `rc-anchor-expired-msg`. I tried `div show` event using this class to fire an event as soon as the session expires and tried to reset recaptcha. But this is not working either.

Is there a callback function or something using which I could reset recaptcha when session expires.

Comment: I'd like to fire an even when the checkbox is checked.  Similar to this question, basically how can we add event handlers to actions for Google's reCaptcha 2?

Answer (score 31):

There is an expired-callback parameter you can pass when rendering the reCAPTCHA which you can then have call the `grecaptcha.reset()` method.

For example:

Put this in the header.

```
<script>
   var callback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('id-of-render-element', {
         'sitekey': 'your-site-key',
         'expired-callback': expCallback
       });
   };
   var expCallback = function() {
      grecaptcha.reset();
   };
</script>
```

Put this after the element that will be used to render the reCAPTCHA.

```
<div id="id-of-render-element"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=callback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

This resets the reCAPTCHA every time the session expires. Got rid of the problem of the `Error: invalid load parameters.` alert window for me.

In case it needs explaining how it works, when the api is loaded it calls the `callback` function from the header script tag. This function renders the reCAPTCHA and declares the `expired-callback` to be the `expCallback` function which just resets the reCAPTCHA back to its orginal state.

You are supposed to be able to use `data-expired-callback` as a tag attribute when automatically rendering the reCAPTCHA (as opposed to rendering it explicitly like above) widget but the callback would not work for me when I tried it that way.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from spaceman is correct. If you wanna do it directly from your `html` tag, then just add `data-expired-callback` attribute with the value of your callback function like this:

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXX" data-expired-callback="handleCaptchaExpired" data-callback="validateCaptcha"></div>
```