# Control TimeOut Of Google Recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha-v3

I want to extend timeout of Google recaptcha control. Can anyone please help me how to extend/control timeout?

I have gone through some of the links in google mentioned below but didn't find any suitable solution till now.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3
[Increase reCAPTCHA session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908959/increase-recaptcha-session-timeout)

Looking forward for the help on this.