# reCaptcha widget doesn't expire and expired callback is never called

Tags: javascript, captcha, recaptcha

I have trouble integrating reCaptcha in my ajax contact form. It works, only for the first 2 minutes after user completed the challenge. ReCaptcha expires after 2 minutes. The problem is that the widget is intact, nothing like "session expired. complete the challenge again". The user is not able to do anything, but reload the page. Also the expired-callback is not called (obviously since the widget doesn't expire).

I could set a timer for 2 minutes upon completion to reset the widget. That would work, but it is a little hacky and what if Google chooses to change expiration time in the future. Any ideas why it won't expire?

I tried both methods of integrating the widget (automatic and explicit)

Edit:
Here is the code, I made a small example html file and proved it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

        <div id="google-recaptcha-widget"></div>

<script>
        var expiredCallback = function() {
            alert('expired!');
        }

        var recaptchaLoad = function() {

                grecaptcha.render('google-recaptcha-widget', {
                        'sitekey' : 'mysitekey'
                        'expired-callback': expiredCallback
                });

        }

</script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaLoad&render=explicit" async defer></script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: I added code, but it is really simple, taken out of example.There is just something wrong with reCaptcha.

Comment: In your code you don't set an expiration callback. No wondering "it does not work"

Comment: It's not about expiration callback. The widget doesn't expire. Normally the widget should turn into "session expired" or something like that. I didn't add expiration callback in this code for simplicity. I had it in my original code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fire event when reCAPTCHA session expires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738949/fire-event-when-recaptcha-session-expires)

Comment: @dana This is a different problem. At least there something happened when session expired, but for me the widget doesn't indicate at all that the session expired,.

Comment: OK - I have retracted my close vote... It seems like you are still missing something here though.  Something in your code (either JS or HTML) might be causing the reCAPTCHA plugin to fail.  Perhaps there is bug in the plugin or maybe you are doing something that is causing it to fail.  Without more details, it will be difficult to figure out though.

Comment: Well, there are no more details. I tested the HTML file I included here. It also fails. It fails on the most basic setup. I solved my problem with a custom solution. If recaptcha is completed and server validation fails, user is informed that reCaptcha expired and the widget is reset with reset method.

Comment: This just started happening to me -- expired-callback was working fine in production, but now the widget doesn't want to expire anymore.  It continues to appear validly answered after the time is up, the callback doesn't fire, and after submission the user gets branded as a bot.  And no errors happen on the JS console.

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk did you solved?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't remember how. I think I just set a timer to manually reset it, or manually reset it in some other way. Now I'm using invisible recaptcha and don't have any problems. And I reset it automatically if the server validation fails. So I guess that's how I solved it before. If server validation fails, return recaptchaError: true in the response, or something like that and reset recaptcha programatically based on that condition.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this? I am having this exact problem. The recaptcha expires behind the scenes after about two minutes but the recaptcha stays checked and the expired callback never fires. I'd rather not set a manual timer to reset this if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="google-recaptcha-widget" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mySiteKey" data-callback="myCallbackMethod" data-expired-callback="expiredCallback"></div>

<script>
    function myCallbackMethod() {
        // save the world
    }

    function expiredCallback() {
        // Uh oh, reCAPTCHA expired, hack the world
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the data-expired-callback wasn't working at all. So my solution was to use PHP to programmatically check if it's been 2 minutes using the 'challenge_ts' timestamp that comes from the json object. I added comments in the code below where the timestamp is actually being handled:

```
$post_data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    )
    );
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $post_data
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);
    $result = json_decode($response);
    // Storing the timestamp when the captcha was generated on the page
    $reCaptchaTS = $result->challenge_ts; 
    $date = new DateTime();
    // Setting the time for the captcha to expire for 2 minutes
    date_add($reCaptchaTS, date_interval_create_from_date_string('2 minutes'));
    if ($result->success) {
        // If 2 minutes have passed since the captcha was generated then it expires, generating an error. 
        if ($date > $reCaptchaTS) {
            $reCaptchaExpiredError = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><b>Error:</b> The reCAPTCHA has expired. Please try again.</div>";
        }
    }
```

So here take the json timestamp and store it in a variable $reCaptchaTS. Then I update the timestamp by adding 2 minutes to it so we can set the time for the CAPTCHA to expire. Then, I create a $date and store the current time in it.

After that, we just check if the user completed the captcha with if ($result->success). There we can finally check if the current time is greater than the expiration time, which means the captcha has expired. At that point I generated my error message called $reCaptchaExpiredError, but you can handle this however you want.